# Laravel artisan migrate multiple database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, laravel-artisan

I am doing some testing with Laravels migration feature.

I have two databases in my config, `mysql` and `appDb`. `mysql` is the default one.
I created two directories in the migrations directory, 
`appDb` and `coreDb`. I created one migration for the `appDb` in the `appDb` directory, and one in the `coreDb` directory for the `mysql` database.

Now, to run the `coreDb` migrations I just use the command

```
php artisan migrate --path database/migrations/coreDb
```

Output:

```
Migrated: 2017_01_25_195008_initial_core_database
```

It works fine, and the table I create in the migration under `coreDb` is now in the database specified in the `mysql` configuration.

Now I want to do the changes i specified in the `appDb` directory, but only on the database specified in the `appDb` configuration.

```
php artisan migrate --database appDb --path database/migrations/appDb
```

It runs fine:

```
Migration table created successfully.
Migrated: 2017_01_25_194957_initial_app_database
```

When I so open up the database specified in the `appDb` config, it shows me the migrations table, and it shows it ran the `2017_01_25_194957_initial_app_database` migration. But the table I create in the `2017_01_25_194957_initial_app_database` migration, has ended up in the other database, which does not have a record for this migration in its migrations table.

It seems like it used the database specified after `--database` to store the information about the migration, but not to actually perform the migration on?

Anyone else had experiences with this?
Ideas for how to debug this?

I also tried to do this:

```
Schema::connection($this->getConnection())->dropIfExists('testAppDb');
```

But the `$this->getConnection()` on the migration class returns `NULL`, even when I have a database specified by the `--database` argument.

Answer (score 0):

You need to name the actual DB you want to connect to in the `Schema::connection()`, in order to perform the migrations for specific DB:

example:

```
Schema::connection('testAppDb')->dropIfExists('testAppDb');
```